# Android Studio Build Problem when including "implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'" in gradle.dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-appcompat

Recently I've upgraded my Android Studio to Arctic Fox patch 4 and my project no longer builds correctly (it used to build correctly before but I forgot which Android Studio version I was in).

The following are 8 task errors shown in Build Output:

```
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED

> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED

> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED

> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies FAILED

> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED
```

I've spent hours trying to fix this issue and I noticed that if I remove the following from build.gradle.dependencies, it'll pass the failures above:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
```

The problem is I need appcompat library primarily for my own class MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
}
```

Appreciate any help I can get from overcoming those 8 task errors above.

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle files?

Comment: I'm having a hard time believing that appcompat is the cause, I just updated to v1.4.1 and build was fine. Please provide all your gradle files.

Comment: Please see my answer below. It was the Guava's listenablefuture errors that were showing in the Build Output. Not sure why appcompat has either a reference or a (dynamic?) link to guava but by excluding it from gradle, I was able to successfully build the gradle

Answer (score 0):

Hi sorry but after more hours of frustration, I finally figured out what went wrong: it was the guava's listenablefuture that's causing all the gradle errors.

To fix this, this is what I did to my build.gradle file:

```
android {

    configurations{
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
    }

...

}

dependencies {
    implementation ('androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
    }

...

}
```